# QThreading in QT and update GUI at the same time

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5, qt-creator

Hello Im trying to print my result from a thread to `textBrower` in `qtwidget QT` but I cant, either I get error or the program wont compile
is there another way ?? how can I change the `textBrowser`  outside of the class's function??

PS BTW I need to keep looping inside the thread cuz actually im getting some data from `uart` in final program (in this code i just wanna print `"lol"` which eventually I wanna change it with some other code which take data ) so I cant come out of the loop
eventually i want use some process from another library and show the resault **REAL TIME**

```
bool stop;

out::out(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::out)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->textBrowser->setText("lol");
}

out::~out()
{
    delete ui;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////

class t : public out, public QThread
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        while(1){
            qDebug()<<"hi"<<i;
           // ui->textBrowser->setText("lol"); I tried to use this but it didnt worked
            if(stop==true){
            QThread::exec();
                    }
        }
    }
};


void mamad1(void){   //this function get called from another cpp file and its for starting the thread
    stop=false;
    t *b = new t;
    b->start();


}

void out::on_pushButton_clicked() // a push button to stop the thread
{
    stop=true;
}
```

I tried make ui in out.h file a public property and use `ui->textBrowser->setText("lol");` but it didn't worked the program freezed and i got this
`error : (Parent is QTextDocument(0x208d812a510), parent's thread is QThread(0x208d6816de0), current thread is QThread(0x208dac94e10)`

I tried to use `connect()` also and didn't worked or I didn't use it right

Comment: For GUI applications, you need to keep all the GUI stuff in a single thread. You can create as many worker-threads as you need and can, but keep all UI work out of them.

Comment: I don't know how the Qt signal/slot system works in regard to threads. But if a thread emits a signal, and the processing and function calling of the signal is handled by the main event thread then use that. Otherwise you need to figure out some other way to propagate signals from the worker threads into the main event-loop handling thread that also does the GUI work.

Comment: In regards to threads you can use Qt:QueuedConnection and that posts a message to the thread's message queue  / event loop instead of processing it directly.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of QT the GUI thread is called the master thread. This thread has an event queue. In general, this event queue is populated by internal and external events. Moreover, the queue between threads is an efficient approach for thread communication. The same is true for the worker threads as well. When you call the start method through the worker threads their signal queue is created and ready to be consumed by the corresponding thread.

Let's come back to your question. The solution is simple. From your worker threads, you can just send a signal to the master thread. The master thread will see this event that modifies the GUI item and forwards this signal/event to the slot that is responsible to take action accordingly. **Just define a signal in your worker thread and connect your master thread to this signal with a given slot.**

### UPDATE FOR SOLUTION

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <MyWorkerThread.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void setWorkerThread(MyWorkerThread* thread);
    void connectToSignals();

public slots:
    void handleTextBoxSignal(const QString& text);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyWorkerThread* m_worker_thread{nullptr};
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MainWindow::setWorkerThread(MyWorkerThread* thread)
{
    m_worker_thread = thread;
}

void MainWindow::connectToSignals()
{
    QObject::connect(m_worker_thread,
                     SIGNAL(changeTextOnUI(QString)),
                     this,
                     SLOT(handleTextBoxSignal(QString)));
}

void MainWindow::handleTextBoxSignal(const QString& text)
{
    qDebug() << "Text box change signal received with text: " << text;
    auto text_box = findChild<QTextEdit*>("myTxtEdit");
    if(text_box != nullptr)
    {
        text_box->setText(text);
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

MyWorkerThread.h

```
#ifndef MYWORKERTHREAD_H
#define MYWORKERTHREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class MyWorkerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyWorkerThread(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    void stopThread();

signals:
    void changeTextOnUI(const QString& text);

private:
    void run() override;

    bool m_exit{false};
};

#endif // MYWORKERTHREAD_H
```

MyWorkerThread.cpp

```
#ifndef MYWORKERTHREAD_H
#define MYWORKERTHREAD_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class MyWorkerThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyWorkerThread(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    void stopThread();

signals:
    void changeTextOnUI(const QString& text);

private:
    void run() override;

    bool m_exit{false};
};

#endif // MYWORKERTHREAD_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    MyWorkerThread* worker_thread = new MyWorkerThread();
    w.setWorkerThread(worker_thread);
    w.connectToSignals();
    worker_thread->start();

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

In the above code, you see the full solution to your problem. In the worker thread, we increment a static counter and concatenate it with a string and send it to the master thread that manages the UI elements. We emit a signal and this signal is landed on the slot. This way the master thread updates the text box on the screen per 5 seconds. The worker thread sleeps for 5 seconds at each iteration.

Comment: hi tnx for the comment , I already tried signal and slot but it didnt worked would you pls give me an example so I can find where Im doing wrong i keep gettint no connect error (i made a `signal:` in my thread class and `emit` it inside the `run` after that i `connect` them but didnt worked) if u can help me write the connect it would be great

Comment: ***I already tried signal and slot but it didnt worked*** It should. This is the most common method. For help with your bug you will have to show code and any error you got.

Comment: well my first problem `void MainWindow::setWorkerThread(MyWorkerThread* thread)` 
my program didnt had this,  but i still cant emit my signal when `run()` is finished or a loop inside it is finished and you didnt put `MyWorkerThread.cpp`  would you pls edit and correct `MyWorkerThread.cpp`  ?? by looking at your code I find out alot about how things in qt works tnx a lot